# Visual Studio 2013 Pro: I've lost ability to browse class members in Solution Explorer

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, solution-explorer

Like the subject says, I've suddenly lost the ability to view class members (properties and methods, or any structure at all) from the Solution Explorer. I've looked in settings unsuccessfully (not that I changed anything), and have tried cleaning the solution, rebuilding, restarting Visual Studio, etc. to no avail. What could be causing this? Thank you.

Comment: Does it no longer work for a particular solution or for all solutions?

Comment: @SergeyVlasov It no longer works for all solutions. :|

Comment: I have a feeling you've probably tried it, but just in case I have to ask the obvious. At the bottom of your Solution explorer, is there a "Class View" tab? If it's there, click it, If it's missing try View / Class View or Ctrl + Shift + C.

Answer (score 0):

This setting is controlled by the **UseSolutionNavigatorGraphProvider** registry value from HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0.

If you have the VSCommands extension installed, you can control it from Tools - Options - VSCommands 12 - IDE Enhancements - Solution Explorer - Disable Graph provider.

Comment: That didn't work. The registry value was missing, and when I installed VSCommands, the disabling setting was unchecked. Unchecking, rechecking, and reinstalling each time did nothing. Thank you, though!

Answer (score 0):

Try using the extension below it might help:

[Disable Solution Explorer's Dynamic Nodes](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/62461a72-4255-4eac-a630-52758e9c3723)

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the below link and enable the settings (set the value to 1) and see if that works.

https://visualstudioextensions.vlasovstudio.com/2013/11/04/hide-class-info-in-visual-studio-20122013-solution-explorer/

Answer (score 0):

Is it website project or web application project? We couldn't see any class member hierarchy in website project.

Answer (score -2):

You can find it in view dropdown menu! and if not then clear your question more please